# part of speech of 'somewhere'

Tags: parts-of-speech

This is the definition of 'drag' in Oxford Learner's Dictionaries.

> [transitive] *drag somebody/yourself + adv./prep.* to persuade
> somebody to come or go **somewhere** they do not really want to come or go
> to

I wonder what part of speech 'somewhere' is in the above definition.

Is it an adverb or a pronoun?

Comment: In traditional grammar it's an adverb. But in modern grammar it's a **compound determinative**. See here: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/somewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an adverb.

It modifies the verb "go". Words that modify verbs are adverbs.

It answers the question "Where to...?". Words and phrases that answer this question are adverbial. This is a single word, so it's an adverb.

If it were a pronoun, it would be a subject or an object, but it's neither.

Comment: If it is an adverb, is 'to' necessary at the end of the definition?

Comment: @ellse No, the "to" at the end of the definition is optional. Without "to", the same meaning is implied.